# Handsontable Data not posting to phpMyAdmin database using PDO query

Tags: mysql, css, pdo, handsontable

I'm having trouble trying to send data from my handsontable table to my SQL database (phpMyAdmin). Data in this table is input by the user and when they click send it will insert all the data into an existing table in my database. Also, if they click load it will load all the all the rows from the database they are saving into. I'm currently working with the following scripts to try and send data to my database.

index.php (relevant code):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>SuburbMap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
    <script src="http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/bower_components/numeraljs/languages/de.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/admin-tools/admin-plugins/admin-panels/adminpanels.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/admin-tools/admin-forms/css/admin-forms.css">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

       <Style>
 #loader {
z-index:99999;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%; left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }       
    body {
background-color: white;
margin: 20px;
    }

   h2 {
margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .handsontable-table {
overflow: scroll;

position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 54px; 

 width: 100%;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="example1" class="dataTable"></div>
    <p>
            <button name="load" id="load">Load</button>
            <button name="save" id="save">Save</button>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="autosave" id="autosave" checked="checked" autocomplete="off"> Autosave</label>
    </p> 

    <script>
    var 
    $container = $("#example1"),
      $console = $("#exampleConsole"),
      $parent = $container.parent(),
      autosaveNotification;
      $container.handsontable({

      startRows: 8,
      startCols: 3,
      rowHeaders: true,
      colHeaders: ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'District/Suburb', 'Zip/Postcode', 'Income', 'No. Items', 'Item/Job Description'],
               columns: [
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
  ],
minSpareCols: 0,
minSpareRows: 1,
contextMenu: true,
contextMenu: {
      callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
    },
            items: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row', 'undo', 'redo', 'copy', 'paste'],
contextMenuCopyPaste: {
  swfPath: '/managers/handsontable/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf'
}
      },
      afterChange: function (change, source) {
        if (source === 'loadData') {
  return; //don't save this change
}
        if ($parent.find('input[name=autosave]').is(':checked')) {
          clearTimeout(autosaveNotification);
          $.ajax({
            url: "/managers/save.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {changes: change}, //contains changed cells' data
            success: function () {
              $console.text('Autosaved (' + change.length + ' cell' + (change.length > 1 ? 's' : '') + ')');
              autosaveNotification = setTimeout(function () {
                $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
              }, 1000);
            }
                  });
        }
      }
            });
    var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');



    $parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
      $.ajax({
url: "/managers/save.php",
data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
        success: function (res) {
          if (res.result === 'ok') {
    $console.text('Data saved');
          }
          else {
    $console.text('Save error');
          }
        },
        error: function () {
  $console.text('Save error');
        }
      });
    });


    $parent.find('button[name=reset]').click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/managers/reset.php",
        success: function () {
          $parent.find('button[name=load]').click();
        },
        error: function () {
          $console.text('Data reset failed');
        }
      });
    });

    $parent.find('input[name=autosave]').click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $console.text('Changes will be autosaved');
      }
      else {
        $console.text('Changes will not be autosaved');
      }
      $parent.find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/load.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (res) {
          var data = [], row;
          for (var i = 0, ilen = res.MultipleTerritories.length; i < ilen; i++) {
            row = [];
            row[0] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].fname;
            row[1] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].lname;
            row[2] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].email;
            row[3] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].suburb;
            row[4] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].postcode;
            row[5] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].revenue;
            row[6] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].noitems;
            row[7] = res.MultipleTerritories[i].typeitems;
            data[res.MultipleTerritories[i].id - 1] = row;
          }
          $console.text('Data loaded');
          handsontable.loadData(data);
        }
      });
    }).click(); //execute immediately
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The following Scripts Are called from the script above:

```
    functions.php script:

    function &getConnection(){
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=suburbma;charset=utf8', 'suburbma***', '*****');


    function closeConnection ($db){
        $db = NULL;
            }

    //create the database if does not exist
            function createMultipleTerritoriesTable($db){
        $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MultipleTerritories (id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fname TEXT, lname TEXT, email TEXT, suburb TEXT, postcode INTEGER, revenue INTEGER, noitems INTEGER, typeitems TEXT)");
            }

            function resetMultipleTerritoriesTable($db){
        dropMultipleTerritoriesTable($db);
        createMultipleTerritoriesTable($db);
        loadDefaultMultipleTerritories($db);
    }

    function dropMultipleTerritoriesTable($db){
      $db->exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS multiple_suburbs");
    }

    function loadDefaultMultipleTerritories($db){
        $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO multiple_suburbs(id, fname, lname, email, suburb, postcode, revenue, noitems, typeitems) VALUES(:id, :fname, :lname, :email, :suburb, :postcode, :revenue, :noitems, :typeitems)');
        $data = array(
       array(
        'id' => 1,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 6,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 7,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 8,
        'fname' => '',
        'lname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'suburb' => '',
        'postcode' => '',
        'revenue' => '',
        'noitems' => '',
        'typitems' => ''
            )
        );

        foreach($data as $index => $value){
    $query->bindValue(':id', $value['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':fname', $value['fname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':lname', $value['lname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':email', $value['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':suburb', $value['suburb'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':postcode', $value['postcode'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':revenue', $value['revenue'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':noitems', $value['noitems'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':typeitems', $value['typeitems'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
        }
    }

    function &loadMultipleTerritories($db){
        $select = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM multiple_suburbs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100');
        $select->execute();

        return $select;
    }

    function multiple_suburbsTableExists($db){
        $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='multiple_suburbs'");

        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        return $row[0] > 0;
    }
```

save.php:

```
     <?php

    require_once('functions.php');
    try {
      //open the database
      $db =  getConnection();
      createMultipleTerritoriesTable($db);

      $colMap = array(
        0 => 'fname',
        1 => 'lname',
        2 => 'email',
        3 => 'suburb',
        4 => 'postocde',
        5 => 'revenue',
        6 => 'noitems',
        7 => 'typeitems'
      );
      if (isset($_POST['changes']) && $_POST['changes']) {
        foreach ($_POST['changes'] as $change) {
          $rowId  = $change[0] + 1;
          $colId  = $change[1];
          $newVal = $change[8];
          if (!isset($colMap[$colId])) {
            echo "\n spadam";
            continue;
          }
          $select = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM multiple_suburbs WHERE id=? LIMIT 1');
          $select->execute(array(
            $rowId
          ));
          if ($row = $select->fetch()) {
            $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE multiple_suburbs SET `' . $colMap[$colId] . '` = :newVal WHERE id = :id');
          } else {
            $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO multiple_suburbs (id, `' . $colMap[$colId] . '`) VALUES(:id, :newVal)');
          }
          $query->bindValue(':id', $rowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $query->bindValue(':newVal', $newVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $query->execute();
        }
      } elseif (isset($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data']) {
        $select = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM multiple_suburbs');
        $select->execute();
        for ($r = 0, $rlen = count($_POST['data']); $r < $rlen; $r++) {
          $rowId = $r + 1;
          for ($c = 0, $clen = count($_POST['data'][$r]); $c < $clen; $c++) {
            if (!isset($colMap[$c])) {
              continue;
    }
    $newVal = $_POST['data'][$r][$c];
    $select = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM multiple_suburbs WHERE id=? LIMIT 1');
    $select->execute(array(
      $rowId
    ));
    if ($row = $select->fetch()) {
      $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE multiple_suburbs SET `' . $colMap[$c] . '` = :newVal WHERE id = :id');
    } else {
      $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO multiple_suburbs (id, `' . $colMap[$c] . '`) VALUES(:id, :newVal)');
    }
    $query->bindValue(':id', $rowId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':newVal', $newVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
          }
        }
      }
      $out = array(
'result' => 'ok'
      );
      echo json_encode($out);
      closeConnection($db);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
              print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
            ?>
```

reset.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once('functions.php');
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        resetMultipleTerritoriesTable($db);
        closeConnection($db);
    }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
        print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

load.php:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * This is an example code that shows how you can load Handsontable data from server using PHP with PDO (SQLite).
     * This code is not intended to be maximally efficient nor safe. It is for demonstrational purposes only.
     * Changes and more examples in different languages are welcome.
     *
     * Copyright 2012, Marcin Warpechowski
     * Licensed under the MIT license.
     * http://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/
     */
    require_once('functions.php');
    try {
      //open the database
      $db = getConnection();
      if(!multiple_suburbsTableExists($db)){
          resetMultipleTerritoriesTable($db);
      }
      //select all data from the table
      $result = loadMultipleTerritories($db);
      $out = array(
        'multiple_suburbs' => $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
      );
      echo json_encode($out);
      // close the database connection
      closeConnection($db);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      print 'Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
    } 
    ?>
```